# Start MATLAB debug mode after stepping out of file

Tags: matlab, debugging

I frequently find myself in the situation, where I insert a lot of `keyboard` commands into my code to debug it.  However, I would like to have a bit more flexibility. That's why I started writing my `stahp` function.

```
function stahp()
disp('Stahp requested.');
dbstack
disp('You can either');
disp('  1 abort.');
disp('  2 continue.');
disp('  3 debug.');

in = input('Choose what to do:\n');

switch(in)
    case 1
        error('Stahp.');
    case 2
        disp('Continue.')
    case 3
        disp('Debug.');
        keyboard % <------------------------------------ Here is my problem
    otherwise
        stahp();
end
end
```

The idea is, to let the user choose, what he wants to do (continue, abort, debug, maybe something else in the future). However, I would prefer to not start the debug mode inside the `stahp` function, but right after stepping out.
For example, when running

```
function test_stahp
a = 1
stahp()
b = 2
end
```

I would like to enter the debug mode right before `b=2`. I assume, that `dbstep out` can somehow be used, but the way I tried it so far, you still have to step manually out of `stahp()`. I am also aware, that the recursive call of `stahp()` in `otherwise` might complicate things, but I could remove that part.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dbstack` to get the current stack and then retrieve the name of the calling function and line number that called `stahp`. Using this info, you can use the `dbstop` to create a breakpoint in the function that performed the function call. The code sample below sets the breakpoint in `test_stahp` on the b=2 line.

```
function stahp()
disp('Stahp requested.');
dbstack
disp('You can either');
disp('  1 abort.');
disp('  2 continue.');
disp('  3 debug.');

in = input('Choose what to do:\n');
r=dbstack;
switch(in)
    case 1
        dbclear(r(2).name,num2str(r(2).line+1));
        error('Stahp.');
    case 2
        dbclear(r(2).name,num2str(r(2).line+1));
        disp('Continue.')
    case 3
        disp('Debug.');
        dbstop(r(2).name,num2str(r(2).line+1))
    otherwise
        stahp();
end
end
```

Comment: There is one problem with this approach. If I select `debug`, this explicitly places a breakpoint at the next line. But if I rerun the code and select `continue` I will still stop at the originally placed breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. One option would be to use `dbclear` to clear the breakpoint. I updated my existing answer so that it removes the breakpoint (if any).

Comment: Thanks, but now, `stahp` is not selfcomplete. I would prefer not adding the `dbclear` everytime I add `stahp`.

Comment: Yeah, a better idea would probably call 'dbclear' at the start of 'stahp'. This way any old breakpoints will always be cleared each time its called. I'll update the code tomorrow once I've had a chance to test it out.

Comment: It seems, that adding `dbclear(r(2).name,num2str(r(2).line+1))  ` to the `continue` and `error` case fixes the problem. A simple `dbclear` at the beginning of the file would clear all breakpoints. If you would include this in your answer, I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: Sure, I updated the code with the dbclear statements you mentioned.